# jQuery animate opacity, remove div and getting invalid argument error within ie8

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, arguments

i got a list of logos, which have to be centered, so far so good.
While accessing the page i've noticed that the pictures got an ugly jump while being positioned.
So i've decided to set a div above those logos, drop opacity from 1 to 0
and finally remove it, so that their are clickable again.

Works very nice in Firefox, Opera, etc. But NOT within IE.

I switched over to the fullversion of jQuery.
The debugger output looks like that:

```
if ( set ) {
 style[ name ] = value;
}
```

Here is the code i use and the html:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
 jQuery(".img_center").each(function(){
  var $li = jQuery(this), $img = $li.find('img');
  $img.css('padding-top', ($li.height() / 2) - ($img.height() / 2));
 });
 jQuery(".overlay_pic").animate({opacity: 0}, 2000, 'swing').queue(function(){
   jQuery(this).remove();
 });
});
```

Html:

```
<li class="img_center">
 <div class="overlay_pic"></div>
 <a href="">
  <img src="image/logos/countryclassics.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
 </a>
</li>
<li style="margin:0;" class="img_center">
 <div class="overlay_pic"></div>
 <a href="">
  <img src="image/logos/donna.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
 </a>
</li>
```

css:

```
.overlay_pic{
 width:inherit;
 height:inherit;
 background:white;
 opacity:1;
 position:absolute;
}
```

any ideas? :/

Edit:
Ok, positioning is the source of that error. The calculation of the padding-top value jumps between correct value and bullshit bingo.

li height (half) normally -> 80, but sometimes just 8. Which results in padding-top -13px.

so, new calculation function for the win?!

Edit3:
Ok, f*** off dynamic calculation...

**SOLUTION**

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
var li = "80";
jQuery(".img_center").each(function(){
    var $li = jQuery(this), $img = $li.find('img');
    $img.css('padding-top', (li) - ($img.height() / 2));
});
jQuery(".overlay_pic").animate({opacity: 0}, 2000, 'swing').queue(function(){
        jQuery(this).remove();
});
```

});

I set the height static, without calculation. Thank god it's not a full dynamic ul li box...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what's happening is your "height" computation is coming up with `NaN`, and IE doesn't like you setting that as the value for "padding-top".  IE will often return "auto" as the value of "height".  You might try changing that to "innerHeight" and see if it helps. (*edit* well now that I think of it the jQuery "height" method *should* always give you a number ... however I still think that the problem somehow lies with the setting of that CSS property. See what the debugger says about the value of "value" at that line inside jQuery.)

Debugging with the unminified jQuery is a great idea. In the debugger, you can click on the "Locals" tab on the right side of the debugger panel to see local variables, and use the "Stack" to walk up the stack and find locals in outer contexts. (Unfortunately, what the IE debugger can't do, as far as I can tell, is show variables in outer scopes that are captured as closures, but that probably wouldn't be a problem in this case.)

*edit again* — ah ok, thanks for posting the link. The problem is that you're trying to set "padding-top" to "-13px", which IE won't allow (and rightly so). That was clear in the debugger just by checking that "Locals" view. To avoid that, just use Math.max:

```
$img.css('padding-top', Math.max(0, ($li.height() / 2) - ($img.height() / 2)));
```

Comment: Thanks for that advice. The error occurs at line 4618 within jQuery.
I had a look up on that local variables, and noticed that opacity at the end of the list is undefined.
But its set to 1 by css, and later to 0 by jQuery... 
Nothing found like NaN :/

Comment: OK I've edited the answer - the problem is that the image height is apparently larger than the `<li>` height, so you're trying to set negative padding and that's not allowed.

Comment: Ah ya, i noticed that -13px too, but didnt knew that it could be the source of all evil. But how do i get around ? :/
And i cant really see any -13px padding across all those logos...

Comment: edited again - just make sure the value isn't less than zero.

Comment: The li is 160x160px, every img has 150px width, and max. height 150px, most of those are under 150px...?!
You mean, i just should check up with an reg-ex if the value is negative and toggle it to positive?!

Comment: Amazing! thanks a lot Pointy, although this means, that the one logo which initiates the problem won't be set centered within the li.
The right value for the 8th logo would be padding-top:59px;
I don't really understand how it comes out with -13px, but than sets the value to 59px. like in ff or opera it does...